# query doesn't return expected result with empty string in condition

Tags: php, mysql

The only condition that is verified from my sql is the one with column 'type', if I comment this one I get the expected results.

```
    $requestData = $this->input->post(null, true);
        $types = [
            0 =>'Processor',
            1 =>'Ram',
            2 => 'Swap',
            3 => 'Service'
        ];
$searchValue = $this->db->escape_str($requestData['search']['value']);
        $value = array_search(strtolower($searchValue), array_map('strtolower',$types));

        if (!empty($requestData['search']['value'])) {
            //$sql .= " AND (endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.type = '" . $value . "' ";
            $sql .= " AND (endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.type LIKE '%" . $value . "%' ";
            $sql .= " OR persoane_contact_fixe.Nume LIKE '%" . $searchValue . "%' ";
            $sql .= " OR persoane_contact_fixe.Prenume LIKE '%" . $searchValue . "%' ";
            $sql .= " OR endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.value LIKE '%" . $searchValue . "%') ";
        }
```

I suspect is a query syntax problem, this is the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(persoane_contact_fixe.Nume, ' ', persoane_contact_fixe.Prenume) as DeviceOwner,
   endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.value as value,
   endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.start_time as startDate,
   endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.type as type FROM 
 endpoint_performance_counters_alerts
   WHERE endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.company = '8'
   AND (endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.type = ''
   OR persoane_contact_fixe.Nume LIKE '%r%'
   OR persoane_contact_fixe.Prenume LIKE '%r%'
   OR endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.value LIKE '%r%')
```

Comment: How does the _entire_ SQL looks like?

Comment: I've updated the post with the whole query.

Comment: If  _$searchValue_ is not equal to one of the _$types_  array values, in query type condition is an empty string.

Comment: are there records where the `endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.type` is literally an empty string? Or... should it be `endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.type IS NULL` as the condition?

Comment: no, endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.type is never an empty string...but i just tried the query with _.type = 1_ and another eligible value on the other columns, and still the result wasn't the expected one (it returned the rows with type column value 1, but not it didn't apply the condition on the other columns)

Comment: Please share some (input)data, and the expected result from that data. (But, why bother, you already "get the expected results."... ??)

Answer (score -2):

Eventually I changed the code like this and it seems to work, but it looks sketchy to me because basically both of the conditions are true, but I suppose once it enters the first one it doesn't matter...:

```
if ($value) {
        $sql .= " AND endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.type LIKE '%" . $value . "%' ";
    } elseif (!empty($requestData['search']['value'])) {
        $sql .= " AND (persoane_contact_fixe.Nume LIKE '%" . $searchValue . "%' ";
        $sql .= " OR persoane_contact_fixe.Prenume LIKE '%" . $searchValue . "%' ";
        $sql .= " OR endpoint_performance_counters_alerts.value LIKE '%" . $searchValue . "%') ";
    }
```